# Как сохранить таблицу из DataGridView1 в БД (SQL Server) в файл .mdf?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, datagridview

Отображаю таблицу так:

```
string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [Товар]";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "[Товар]");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Товар]"].DefaultView;
```

А вот как сохранить? Может кто поможет с этим?
Писал так но коряво

```
int rowCounter = dataGridView1.RowCount;
    int columnCount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
    string[] line = new string[columnCount];
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 варианта: полегче и посложнее.

1 - [Построчно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556556/insert-all-data-of-a-datagridview-to-database-at-once)...

```
var connString = "MyConnectionString";

try
{   
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var strQuery = "INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, ...)" + 
                           "VALUES (@param1, @param2, ...)";
                comm.CommandText = strQuery;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[myColName1].Text);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[myColName2].Text);
                // больше параметров ...
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

2 - Через [BulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) (и хранимые).

```
// приводим к DataTable а потом пушим во временную таблицу, например.
DataTable data = (DataTable)(dgvMyMembers.DataSource);
```

Хотя я рекомендовал бы второй подход **только** если вы знаете что делаете, а т.ж. у вас большой (очень большой) объем данных.

Comment: @ Kirill 'luridSNK' F. не селен в C# может поможете сделать для моего кода.. дальше я по анологии

Comment: @user298338 настолько "не селен", что не можете увидеть, что в "первом варианте" для вас уже сделали готовый пример, который и нужно подбить к своему по, как вы выразились, аналогии? Всего-то подставить строку подключения и обратиться к dataGridView по имени колонки...

Comment: 30 не заметил! Вам спасибО!)

Comment: @user298338 Пожалуйста. Вы, главное, ответ отметьте, если уж помогло.

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. по личному опыту, рекомендую вам никогда не отвечать на вопросы от пользователей с таким вот именем как `userНомер`. Таких пользователей создают под единственный вопрос и в случае получения помощи никогда не благодарят. Помогая таким вот людям вы не заработаете рейтинг и даже не получите в ответ, спасибо. Так что просто игнорируйте впредь вопросы от таких вот учёток.

Comment: @Bulson да ладнО? не поблагодарил.. эмм вы обижены просто

Comment: @user298338 Пожалуйста. Вы, главное, ответ отметьте, если уж помогло

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, вам нужно не *сохранить*, а *обновить* данные. Пользователь мог в датагриде какие-то данные добавить, изменить или удалить.

Для этого нужно вызвать метод [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/at8a576f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Чтобы он правильно отработал, должны быть заданы свойства [InsertCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), `UpdateCommand`, `DeleteCommand`. В примере написано, как это сделать.

Подробнее смотрите [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters).